# Why must adversative coordination be binary?

Tags: syntax, semantics, coordination

At Glottopedia we read that [adversative coordination](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Adversative_coordination) expresses semantic contrast between the coordinands. In English, adversative coordination is usually accomplished with “but,” as in these sentences.

> “The Hendersons were poor, but happy.”
>
> “He tried the door, but it was locked.”

In this article on [Coordination](http://www.beck-shop.de/fachbuch/leseprobe/9780521581578_Excerpt_001.pdf), we read that adversative coordination is always binary.  In other words, adversative coordination can only involve two coordinands.   Hence these two sentences are ungrammatical.

1. *The queen tried to kill Snow White but Snow White escaped but she went through much hardship.
2. *The mountain climbers were tired but happy but bankrupt.

So my question is, why are these sentences ungrammatical?    Is the reason syntactic or semantic?  If the answer is lengthier than space on Stack Exchange allows, is there a link to a paper or book with the answer to this question?

Comment: Could anyone tell me how to do hyperlinks on this site?   I've rarely created hyperlinks.  Thanks!

Comment: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Great question James! This has really got me thinking. I initially thought that the problem could've been an overt *but* linking the first two coordinates. In English, all but the final *and* is usually dropped, e.g. *The queen tried to kill snow white, she escaped, and she went through much hardship*. If we drop the initial *but* though, it's impossible to get the right interpretation, e.g. ???*The queen tried to kill snow white, she escaped, but she went though much hardship*. There certainly isn't an adversative relation encoded between coordinates 1 and 2 there. Really curious.

Comment: I should think that the obvious answer is ambiguity: in *A but B but C*, does C contrast with B, with A, or with [A but B]?

Comment: @StoneyB yes, well we would expect it to be ambiguous, but that's not really an answer to the question. The fact is that the readings we would expect to be available aren't - the sentence as a whole just sounds infelicitous.

Comment: @PElliott But it becomes felicitous if you resolve the ambiguity through intonation/punctuation and adjuncts: *A but B—but also C*. "The Queen tried to kill Snow White, but she escaped. But she subsequently went through many hardships."

Comment: @StoneyB although your comment does raise a helpful point. Logical conjunction & disjunction are both associative, i.e. *A & (B & C) <-> (A & B) & C*, whereas the adversative relation, which i'm going to gloss as a logical connective ACTUALLY clearly isn't, i.e. *A ACTUALLY (B ACTUALLY C) !<-> (A ACTUALLY B) ACTUALLY C*. Maybe something to work from here.

Comment: @StoneyB Re your last comment, what is the intended reading for the example you give? It still sounds fairly degraded to me. Can you also suggest what prosody you would use to get the alternative reading?

Comment: @PElliott (Q1) The problem then is that there is no operator precedence rule for *but*. (Q2) Alas, you're getting beyond my skills—I don't know how to notate the prosody. But it depends on whether the final component is an afterthought or a climax.

Comment: @PElliott It ain't graceful, but it happens; here's a field example: "Normally we finish, with all of harvest we shoot for like November first to be done with corn and soybeans total, but usually we don’t cut a bean til the first of October with the maturity we plant. But we may be done picking corn for a few weeks before we cut any beans, but yeah corn harvest is a month ahead of time, we started a month early and we’re probably going to get done a month early."

Comment: _But_ is [logically](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) _and_, but with an added presupposition that some expectation is contradicted. That's pragmatic, not semantic, so the difference between _and_ and _but_ can be ignored, logically. Unlike, for instance, the difference between _and_ and _or_.

Comment: It's syntactic.  "But" connects two constituents.  You can contrast more than two things, you just can't use "but" to do it.

Answer (score -1):

***Why are these sentences ungrammatical?***

Because when "but" is used twice in one sentence, it's not clear what the author means, as "but" implies a strong counterpoint to another thing, but if there are two other things, then the way their counterpoints apply to each other is unclear (and often in practice, doesn't make complete sense).

***Is the reason syntactic or semantic?***

Both, but I expect that the reason for the syntactic rule is the semantic mess made by using two "buts".

More detail:

It seems to me that the issue is more the re-use of the word "but" (which is used to frame an entire clause as an opposition) and the question thus created about the relation between the first part and the third. It has me wondering, "why is the author is strangely using "but" twice like that?" Compare to the same structure with one "yet" and one "but":

- The queen tried to kill Snow White **but** Snow White escaped **yet** she went through much hardship.
- The queen tried to kill Snow White **yet** Snow White escaped **but** she
  went through much hardship.
- The mountain climbers were tired **but** happy **yet** bankrupt.
- The mountain climbers were tired **yet** happy **but** bankrupt.

This is still awkward, but clearer. The author hopefully means that the "but" relation is the major opposition of the clause, while the "yet" is a secondary opposition which can be of a different type (and sentence-grammar-analyzers can ignore it).

When "but" is used twice, it suggests to me that the same type of opposition applies between three expressions, which asks the readers to form a kind of logical triangle in their minds all at once, where the relation between all three may not be so clear or even make sense. When I read two "buts" in a row, I tend to think, "wait, what?" and stop to consider the three potential implied relationships, and whether they're all the same or different.

That is, in "1 but 2 yet 3", 1 and 3 are both adverse to something about 2, but 1 and 3 may not be adverse to each other - they may be about different things. In both of the examples above, this seems to be because the subject is a person and their well-being is the concern of the sentence, and a person has various aspects to their well-being.

So consider the edit:

- The queen tried to kill Snow White but Snow White escaped. She escaped but went through much hardship.

This clarifies that there are two relationships, and does not have me thinking what the original single sentence with two "buts" did, which was: *So is the author implying some relationship between "The queen tried to kill Snow White" and "she went through much hardship", or are they just writing sloppily?*